# Outlook VBA macro to forward email attachment, but delete message body

Tags: microsoft-outlook, vba

I am trying to add a custom action to a rule in Outlook where a message is automatically forwarded and the attachment stays but the original body message is deleted.

I need to write code for the 'clear contents' part. So far have this:

```
Public Sub MyMacro(msg As MailItem)
  Dim strID As String
  Dim olNS As NameSpace
  Dim olMail As MailItem

  strID = msg.EntryID
  Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

  With olMail.HTMLBody = " "
  End With

  Set olMail = Nothing
  Set olNS = Nothing
End Function
```

after the .HTMLBody I can't get it to delete anything.

Edit: Added the actual requirement hidden in the comment. "I need the original e-mail contents deleted including who its from. Basically so that it looks like a brand new e-mail."

Answer (score 0):

The "With" statement allows you to reference multiple properties of an object (olMail in this case) in a block.

Since you're only setting a single property, then there's no need to use the "With" block.  So, try it without the "With/End With" statements, by using just `olMail.HTMLBody = ""`, and remove the `End With` line.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't delete everything. I need the original e-mail contents deleted including who its from. Basically so that it looks like a brand new e-mail.

Comment: Well the "From" field, etc are not the "Body" field. So you'll have to deal with those properties separately.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot see how the code would do anything given the with statement and

Public **Sub** and End **Function**

Note: Untested code. There may be typos and other problems

```
Public Sub MyMacro(msg As MailItem)
  Dim strID As String
  Dim olNS As NameSpace
  Dim olMail As MailItem

  Dim olMailFwd as Mailitem

  strID = msg.EntryID
  Set olNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
  Set olMail = olNS.GetItemFromID(strID)

  'With olMail
  '  .HTMLBody = " "
  'End With

  Set olMailFwd = olMail.Forward

  With olMailFwd
      .HTMLBody = ""
      .subject = olMail.subject ' No FW:
      .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
  end with

  olMailFwd.display
  ' after initial testing change to
  ' olMailFwd.Send

  Set olMailFwd = Nothing
  Set olMail = Nothing
  Set olNS = Nothing

End Sub
```

Unless there is more you have not shared.

```
Public Sub MyMacro(msg As MailItem)

  Dim olMailFwd as Mailitem

  Set olMailFwd = msg.Forward

  With olMailFwd
      .HTMLBody = ""
      .subject = msg.subject ' No FW:
      .To = "someone@somewhere.com"
  end with

  olMailFwd.display
  ' after initial testing change to
  ' olMailFwd.Send

  Set olMailFwd = Nothing

End Sub
```